# Can not get ScrollView to scroll when soft keyboard is shown

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I have been trying to get this scrollview to scroll, and have not had any luck in doing so.
I have tried many types of fixes but cant seem to get one working. I would like to be able to scroll through my page when an edit box is selected and the keyboard takes up half the screen. This way i can navigate to the rest of the edit boxes and the accept button on the bottom of the page, with out having to manually hide the keyboard every time.

Here is my xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@drawable/asuswallpaper4"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:weightSum="1"
      >



        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="#AAA"
          android:text="Input Configuration"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
          android:textColor="#000" >
         </TextView>

             <ScrollView
               android:id="@+id/input_scroll_view"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

               <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >



                      <LinearLayout
                       android:id="@+id/linearLayout10"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                       android:orientation="horizontal" >

                      <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/textView13"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:text="TextView"
                       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                       android:textColor="#000"
                       android:textStyle="bold" >
                      </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enable or Disable"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFF" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/DisableEnable"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/disableButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Disable"
                    android:textColor="#FFF" >
                </RadioButton>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/enableButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                    android:text="Enable"
                    android:textColor="#FFF" >
                </RadioButton>
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- <LinearLayout -->
        <!-- android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" -->
        <!-- android:layout_width="match_parent" -->
        <!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:layout_marginTop="20dp" -->
        <!-- android:orientation="horizontal" > -->


        <!-- <TextView -->
        <!-- android:id="@+id/textView14" -->
        <!-- android:layout_width="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:text="TextView" -->
        <!-- android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" -->
        <!-- android:textColor="#000" -->
        <!-- android:textStyle="bold" -->
        <!-- android:visibility="invisible" > -->
        <!-- </TextView> -->


        <!-- <TextView -->
        <!-- android:id="@+id/textView3" -->
        <!-- android:layout_width="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:text="Positive/Negative Trigger" -->
        <!-- android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" -->
        <!-- android:textColor="#FFF" -->
        <!-- android:visibility="invisible" > -->
        <!-- </TextView> -->
        <!-- </LinearLayout> -->


        <!-- <LinearLayout -->
        <!-- android:id="@+id/linearLayout4" -->
        <!-- android:layout_width="match_parent" -->
        <!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:orientation="vertical" > -->


        <!-- <RadioGroup -->
        <!-- android:id="@+id/PosNeg" -->
        <!-- android:layout_width="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:orientation="horizontal" -->
        <!-- android:visibility="invisible" android:clickable="false"> -->


        <!-- <RadioButton -->
        <!-- android:id="@+id/positive_trigger" -->
        <!-- android:layout_width="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:checked="true" -->
        <!-- android:text="Positive" -->
        <!-- android:textColor="#FFF" android:clickable="false"> -->
        <!-- </RadioButton> -->


        <!-- <RadioButton -->
        <!-- android:id="@+id/negative_trigger" -->
        <!-- android:layout_width="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" -->
        <!-- android:text="Negative" -->
        <!-- android:textColor="#FFF" android:clickable="false"> -->
        <!-- </RadioButton> -->
        <!-- </RadioGroup> -->
        <!-- </LinearLayout> -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Type of Trigger"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/TypeTrigger"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="invisible" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/constant_trigger"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Constant"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:visibility="visible" >
                </RadioButton>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/pulse_trigger"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                    android:text="Pulse"
                    android:textColor="#FFF" >
                </RadioButton>
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=": Continuous or One Time (One Time Only Available for                         Pulsed Input(s))"  
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/contOneTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="invisible" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/continuous_trigger"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Continuous" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/oneTime_trigger"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:text="One Time" />
            </RadioGroup>
           </LinearLayout>

           <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Timer Configuration For Selected Input"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </TextView>
           </LinearLayout>


           <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Number of Pulses"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </TextView>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/NumberOfPulses"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="0"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:numeric="integer"
                android:visibility="invisible" >

                <requestFocus>
                </requestFocus>
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.34"
                android:text=" within,"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </TextView>
           </LinearLayout>

           <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Minutes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.00"
                android:hint="0"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:numeric="integer"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.00"
                android:text="Minutes,"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </TextView>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Seconds"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.00"
                android:hint="0"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:numeric="integer"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Seconds,"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </TextView>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Milliseconds"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.00"
                android:hint="0"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:numeric="integer"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Milliseconds."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.00"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout13"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/inputAccept"
                android:layout_width="159dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.04"
                android:text="Accept" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/inputSave"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.06"
                android:text="Save"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/inputLoad"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.05"
                android:text="Load"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
                </Button>
            </LinearLayout>
         </LinearLayout>
       </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

(Please someone help me figure this thing out, its driving me crazy!!).
I would also like to mention that I have tried most of the fixes with people who had similar issues such as filling the view port, and enabling the vertical scroll bar, non of these helped me with my troubles. I also tried adding them to the parent layout and did not seem to work either.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: Ok, so you're saying you want to be able to scroll when the keyboard is visible? But every time you click outside the keyboard screen, it closes, right? -- If so, that's how the keyboard is designed. When it's target input view loses focus, it closes because it no longer has focus on the target view.

Comment: No thats not my issue. My issue is when the keyboard pops up I can not scroll to the other text boxes in my app. I have to hide to keyboard to see them and enter text. I want to be able to scroll through it.

Comment: @shant please see Alex Lockwood's suggestion there. We are all basically in it for the reputation points here...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to the `<activity>`  tag in your AndroidManifest.xml. This will cause the screen to be resized to the space left over after the software keyboard is shown. As a result, you will be able to scroll, since the screen will not be covered by the keyboard in any way.

EDIT:

I have written a minimal example and tested it. Unless there is a huge misunderstanding, try this code and then figure out why yours doesn't work:

**xml layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="2000dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:text="Scroll Down!"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:hint="Enter Text"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
                >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I added what you suggested to the activity tag in the manifest, and the keyboard still covers the screen with out re sizing and I still can not scroll!

Comment: @Shant, try making the ScrollView the outer-most element in the layout. Just move the xmlns into it as well.

Comment: Did as you suggested...still no go. Still cant get this damn thing to scroll.

Comment: I am currently facing the same issue. And I am trying to call scrollTo(..., myScrollView.bottom()) to scroll all the way to bottom of the page when an EditText is in focus. But this does not work. I think the issue is scrollTo() does not understand the "adjustResize" and thinks that it cannot scroll to the Bottom of the page.

Answer (score 6):

Hi I encountered this problem as well. The issue I had was I added adjustResize as shown below in my Manifest

and it still wouldn't scroll. But in my xml file in the beginning of my ScrollView

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
```

I deleted android:scrollbars="none" and that solved my problem. Just for anyone whose adjustment on the manifest did not work.

Comment: I also faced this issue deleting android:scrollbars="none" worked for me :)