# how to scroll up layout when keyboard visible in activity with FULL_SCREEN

Tags: android, scrollview, android-fullscreen, soft-input-panel

I want to scroll up my layout when softinput keyboard is visible.I have define scrollview in my xml at proper place but when keyboard is visible it hides some part of layout like buttons.
I have read on stackoveflow [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible) that scrollview not works when activity is FULL_SCREEN.If it is true then how can I scroll up my layout when softinput visible.

Comment: show us your code plz

Comment: <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrol"android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">        
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    
     <EditText android:id="@+id/test1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/test"
        /></RelativeLayout>
       </ScrollView>

Comment: may be this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298479/can-not-get-scrollview-to-scroll-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown make your scroll view parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this custom relative layout to detect softkeyboard with in ur xml

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

 /**
 * RelativeLayout that can detect when the soft keyboard is shown and hidden.
 *  
 */

public class RelativeLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard extends RelativeLayout {

public RelativeLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public interface Listener {
    public void onSoftKeyboardShown(boolean isShowing);
}
private Listener listener;
public void setListener(Listener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    Activity activity = (Activity)getContext();
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
    int statusBarHeight = rect.top;
    int screenHeight = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    int diff = (screenHeight - statusBarHeight) - height;
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onSoftKeyboardShown(diff>128); // assume all soft keyboards are at least 128 pixels high
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);       
}

}
```

Then implements RelativeLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard.Listener to your Actiity class

```
   RelativeLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard mainLayout =  (RelativeLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard)V.findViewById(R.id.dealerSearchView);
   mainLayout.setListener(this);




    @Override
public void onSoftKeyboardShown(boolean isShowing) {
    if(isShowing) {


    } else {

    }
}
```

Based on the Keyboard visibility move your layout to up and down using Layout params

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your manifest file

in your activity tag

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" 
add this.

see this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: I have already define android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan" but still its not working