# Softkeypad push Bottom Action Bar when Edittext get focus

Tags: android

I am using

```
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

for Bottom Action Bar .

and this

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

for adjusting view when soft keypad  appears .
But problem is that when keypad opens bottom action bar goes upon keypad like in figure.I want this at bottom even when keypad open.If I don't use "adjustResize" it remains at bottom but when keypad open my view is not scrollable, I can't see whole view.I want both the things means Bottom action bar should remain at bottom and view should remains scrollable .

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/action_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".AddScreen" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/add_et_task_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/add_et_task_remarks"
                android:hint="Task Name" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/add_et_task_remarks"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:hint="Remarks"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:lines="3" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="#b2b2b2" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: "If I don't use "adjustResize" it remains at bottom but when keypad open my view is not scrollable". Are you using `scrollView` in your xml?

Comment: yes I am using scrollview.

Comment: can you show your xml code?

Comment: I have added my xml please help .

Comment: Use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`. Other thing that I think is, you are using `Emulator` so scroll from mouse some times difficult try to run on real device it will definitely scroll.

Comment: I have tried "adjustPan" now but it still same problem once keypad appears I can't scroll up to see all the views. I am trying on device.

Answer (score 3):

If its full screen,

then just

Instead of this line

@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.FullScreen in menefesto

put this line

@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar

and I am sure its gonna solve your problem

OR

PUT

IN ACTIVITY TAG PUT android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Thanks ,

Sal

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem seems to be same as like question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15440786/2311051) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11298752/2311051) Check this out.

Comment: Thanks for answer but those link couldn't help. Actually here problem is Bottom Action Bar which I want to fix at bottom always.

Comment: you didn't show your actionBar code in xml. Have you tried `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` within actionbar tag?

Comment: That action bar is default action bar which is set as bottom action bar here. I am not  adding any view for that .Views are created by adding menu items in menu xml.