# Android Scroll view is not working when keyboard comes

Tags: android

scroll view is working without keyboard But it is not working when keyboard comes i have also tried "android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" no use i dont understand please explain what is happening `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
   >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

       >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"

               >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight=".85"
                    android:background="@drawable/logo" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight=".15"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Fill in the below to get Started"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/sig_user"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"

                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounder_edittext"
                    android:hint="  User name"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/user"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/sig_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/lock"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounder_edittext"
                    android:hint=" Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"

                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/sig_email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"

                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounder_edittext"
                    android:hint="  E-mail"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/mail"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/sig_phone"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/phone"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounder_edittext"
                    android:hint="  Phone"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"

                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/signup"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/white_button"
                    android:text="creat account"
                    android:textColor="#f29925" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

`

Comment: Nigin i just copy and paste your code and its working. please remove "android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" and try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not get ScrollView to scroll when soft keyboard is shown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298479/can-not-get-scrollview-to-scroll-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown)

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"` to your tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. This will cause the screen to be resized to the left over space after the soft keyboard is shown. So, you will be able to scroll easily.

In `Manifest.xml` file like this.

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
                >
```